# Page title for web app using HtmlService

Tags: google-apps-script

With UIApp, you can set the `<title>` of the page via `setTitle()`. I can't figure out how to do it if I'm using an HTML template with HtmlService. I have tried placing `<title>` tags in different spots within the template to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setTitle(String)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HtmlOutput (what you get from template.evaluate() or just from HtmlService.createHtmlOutput() directly) also has a setTitle.